# Can ReSharper use keyword for declarations but type name for member access?

Tags: c#, resharper

ReSharper has features that look for inconsistencies in the use of keywords aliasing a type name.  For example, it would see these two declarations and urge you to change one to be like the other (depending on which is set as your preference):

```
string myString1 = "String 1";
String myString2 = "String 2";
```

This is handy, because I always prefer using the keyword alias for the CLR types when declaring variables, and thus in the above example, I would want to correct the second line.  However, this is also problematic because when using static members of the CLR types, I always prefer to use the type names and NOT the keywords.  Consider the below example:

```
string myString1 = "String 1";
string myString2 = String.Format("{0} is String 1.", myString1);
```

If the option is set to prefer using the keyword, then ReSharper does not complain about the declarations, but it DOES complain about using the type name to access the static String.Format() method.

So, my question is... Is there any way to configure ReSharper such that it will prefer keywords for declarations but type names for static member access?  In other words, can I configure it to not complain about any of the code in my second example above.

Comment: Are you also using Stylecop, by any chance?  You'd need to change rule [SA1121](http://stylecop.soyuz5.com/SA1121.html) as well...

Comment: @PatrickQuirk No, I'm not, but thanks for supplying a possibly pertinent tip for others.

Comment: I'm of the same favor as @bubbleking, it is a much nice style to use keywords for variable declaration (returns, params etc) and the CLR type for method access. Is there a feature vote-up for ReSharper?

Comment: There is a [feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-437913#tab=Comments), but you can't vote for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can`t do that on ReSharper, it is already suggested, as in your post comments, in [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-437913). Anyways, the best thing you can do is ignoring it, i made [a gif for it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwQXk.gif) (Please, ignore other codelines in the gif). I'm using ReSharper 9.1.3, FSF Licensed. I hope this helps.

Comment: Very strange you just posted this as within the last half hour I posted the request in the comments of the ReSharper documentation.

Comment: coincidence, i suppose?

Comment: Indeed. I was puzzled at how you were able to link my Twitter and SO accounts but turns out you didn't!

Answer (score 1):

As of R# 2018.2, this is now possible:

[image]

Comment: This is great.  Now I wish they would let us throw a warning or error when someone uses the keyword with a static member.  In other words, I want to ENFORCE, not just ALLOW the use of keywords with declarations and type names with member access.

Comment: @bubbleking Well, you can set it to Error severity, but you'd have to share it in the team-wide R# settings layer. Or implement a custom Roslyn Analyzer.